# which one have better performance: tab expression, temp table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

if a query need a temp result,there are 3 options in SQL Server 2008:

1. Use it in query as dynamic result, like

   Select * from tab1 a join (select * from tab2) b on a.ID = b.ID
2. Use temp table:

   select * int #tmptab from tab2

   Select * from tab1 a join #tmptab b on a.ID = b.ID
3. Use tab expression:

   With myTab as (select * from tab2)
   Select * from tab1 a join myTab b on a.ID = b.ID

Question is: which one is the best solution with best performance?

Comment: There will be no difference between 1 and 3 and 2 will be slower. But that is only true for the example queries you have here. You have to test your real queries to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server actually stores some `join` results in a temporary table, even if you didn't ask for it.  In those cases a temporary table is identical to a table expression and there is no performance difference.

A temporary table does reduce the freedom of the query optimizer.  For example:

```
select * into #tmptab from tab2

select * from tab1 a join #tmptab b on a.ID = b.ID
```

While processing the first step, the query optimizer doesn't know that it's only looking for values from `tab2` that have a corresponding row in `tab1`.  When processing the second step, the query optimzer has only the temporary table to work with.  It can't make use of any indexes on `tab2`.

So in general, a table expression is superior because it gives the optimizer more freedom.  There are, however, a few cases where you can use a temporary table to force the query optimizer to behave in a certain way.  Use that with caution, after testing, and only if it's really required.

Comment: SQL Server does not need to store join results in any way, to be clear. It only does so if it thinks it is faster than any other way. I think it came across the wrong way in this answer.